# CKEditor option startupMode causes js error

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I was trying to find out what is wrong with this code for a few hours. After double-clicking on divs CKEditor correctly opens and after pressing down the button it correctly hides. But after clicking again on div it doesn't want to open again and then firebug returns an error **"p is null" in line 86 in ckeditor.js**.

Finally it turned out that the problem disappears when I turn off the option **"startupMode: 'source'"**. Has anyone an idea what this behaviour is caused by? Is it a bug in CKEditor or I do something wrong.
Version of CKEditor I use is 3.6.4.
Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/admin/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Vars</h2> 

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell no 1.1</td>
            <td><div class="editable" id="cell1">Cell no 1.2</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell no 2.1</td>
            <td><div class="editable" id="cell2">Cell no 2.2</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Close"/>

<script type="text/javascript">

editor = false; 

function destroy_cke() {
    if (editor) {
        editor.updateElement();
        editor.destroy();
    }
}

function replace_div(div) {
    destroy_cke();
    editor = CKEDITOR.replace(div,{
        startupMode: 'source',
    });
}
$(document).ready (function() { 
    $('.editable').dblclick(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var element = e.target || e.srcElement;
        while (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'html' && (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'div' || element.className.indexOf('editable') == -1 )) element = element.parentNode;
        replace_div(element);
    });

    $('#submit').click(function(){
        destroy_cke();
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered at http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=26734&p=67792#p67792

The `destroy_cke` function isn't clearing the `editor` variable.